# How to count number of days between two dates in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried this way

```
select tv.reg_number, tv.make, tv.model, tev.date_taken,tev.date_return, count(tev.date_taken, tev.date_return) as day_difference
from table_vehicle tv, table_evehicle tev
where tv.reg_number=tev.reg_number
and tev.date_return is not null
group by tv.reg_number, tv.make, tv.model, tev.date_taken, tev.date_return;
```

Is anyone able to help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting one date from another will yield the number of days between the two dates, so assuming both `tev.date_taken` and `tev.date_return` of the `DATE` data type, you can use `tev.date_return - tev.date_taken as day_difference` to get the number of days between the two dates.  If `tev.date_taken` and/or `tev.date_return` contain a time components the returned number may include a fractional portion.  If you don't want the fractional day, you can `TRUNC`ate, `ROUND` or take the `CEIL`ing of the resulting value.

However, if either value is a `TIMESTAMP` the resulting value will be an `INTERVAL` data type.  If this is the case, then you can either cast the `TIMESTAMP` values to `DATE` values, or `EXTRACT(DAY FROM (tev.date_return - tev.date_taken)) as day_difference` to get just the truncated numeric number of days between the two dates.